# How to get element by id after id dynamically added to element?

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom

I have a button with empty `id` attribute. I want to get `<a>` by id that added dynamically to it.

note : I don't want to use `createElement()` to add `<a>`.

HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
  <a id="" class="btn" href="#"><button>Green</button></a><br><br>
  <a id="changeId" href="#"><button>Change Id!</button></a>
</body>
</html>
```

JS

```
$(document).ready(function() {

  $("a#green").on("click", function(){
    $("body").css("background-color","green");
  });
  $("a#changeId").on("click", function(){
    $("a.btn").attr("id","green");
  });

});
```

Here is my code on [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/bahmanparsamanesh/6kegj2a7/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since `id` is being created through another event, you can use event-delegation approach:

```
$("body").on("click","a#green", function(){
```

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  $("body").on("click","a#green", function(){
    $("body").css("background-color","green");
  });
  $("a#changeId").on("click", function(){
    $("a.btn").attr("id","green");
  });

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<body>
  <a id="" class="btn" href="#"><button>Green</button></a><br><br>
  <a id="changeId" href="#"><button>Change Id!</button></a>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

Okay:

```js
 $(document).ready(function() {

      $("a#changeId").on("click", function(){
        $("a.btn").attr("id","green");
        $("a#green").on("click", function(){
            $("body").css("background-color","green");
      });
      });
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

`$(document).on("click", '#green', function(){});` is what you need. Because `$("a#green")` cannot be found because it is dynamically added to DOM. Or you can do some thing like `$('body').on("click", '#green', function(){});` i.e. you need to take reference of static element. It can be any parent element of `#green` that is static.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
 $(document).on("click", '#green', function(){
   $("body").css("background-color","green");
  });
  $("a#changeId").on("click", function(){
   $("a.btn").attr("id","green");
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a id="" class="btn" href="#"><button>Green</button></a><br><br>
  <a id="changeId" href="#"><button>Change Id!</button></a>
```